# installing SparkR package in Ubuntu

Tags: r, scala, ubuntu, sparkr

I am an amateur in working with linux, and only just found my feet with working with R. We've setup a cluster using the HDP 2.2.6.0 with Ambari 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 with spark 1.2.1 scala 2.10.4 installed

Whilst using Rstudio server to install sparkR from the amplab-extras source I am getting the following error. Can somebody help with this? I understand that SparkR has been added to the latest version of Spark 1.5.0, However, we are unable to upgrade at the moment.

```
> library("devtools", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
> library("rJava", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
> install_github("amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg",subdir="pkg")

Downloading GitHub repo amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg@master
Installing SparkR
/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
/tmp/RtmpnSUmAl/devtoolsa3f4787e0dc/amplab-extras-SparkR-pkg-e532627/pkg'  \
'  --library='/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2'  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘SparkR’ ...
** libs
** arch - 
./sbt/sbt assembly
/bin/bash: ./sbt/sbt: Permission denied
make: *** [target/scala-2.10/sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar] Error 126
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘SparkR’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/SparkR’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Similar error in terminal

```
root@ahs02:/home/user/SparkR-pkg# ./install-dev.sh
* installing *source* package ‘SparkR’ ...
** libs
** arch - 
./sbt/sbt assembly
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.6.jar
Invalid or corrupt jarfile sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.6.jar
make: *** [target/scala-2.10/sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘SparkR’
* removing ‘/home/user/SparkR-pkg/lib/SparkR’
```

Comment: It looks to me like you might be having an error with permissions on your system.  I would recommend you check the documentation for what you're using to see if installations need to be performed by the super user (if they tell you to execute `sudo su` or if you see `sudo` before any commands, that means super user).

Comment: @peter-neyens thanks for the formatting help. 
Does the user permissions affect even whilst running the commands in Rstudio server? Also, I checked and the user we are using has "sudo" privileges. The documentation has no mention of adapting the command for user privileges [link] (https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/)

I have also tried to install using the git clone method and come with I believe a similar error. Would the two of them be related? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is `sbt` script executable? On a side note SparkR on 1.2  is kind of waste of time. Anything you write won't be forward compatible.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance here, How do I check if the sbt script is executable?